# Staying DRY with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to minimize repeated code for a number of JAX-RS resource handlers, all of which require a few of the same path and query parameters. The basic url template for each resource looks like this:

```
/{id}/resourceName
```

and each resource has multiple subresources:

```
/{id}/resourceName/subresourceName
```

So, resource/subresource paths (incl. query parameters) might look like

```
/12345/foo/bar?xyz=0
/12345/foo/baz?xyz=0
/12345/quux/abc?xyz=0
/12345/quux/def?xyz=0
```

The common parts across resources `foo` and `quux` are `@PathParam("id")` and `@QueryParam("xyz")`. I *could* implement the resource classes like this:

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService
{
    @PathParam("id") String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") String xyz;
    
    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

```
// QuuxService.java
@Path("/{id}/quux")
public class QuxxService
{
    @PathParam("id") String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") String xyz;
    
    @GET @Path("abc")
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("def")
    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

I've managed to avoid repeating the parameter injection into every single `get*` method.<sup>1</sup>  This is a good start, but I'd like to be able to avoid the repetition across resource classes as well. An approach that works with CDI (which I also need) is to use an `abstract` base class which `FooService` and `QuuxService` could `extend`:

```
// BaseService.java
public abstract class BaseService
{
    // JAX-RS injected fields
    @PathParam("id") protected String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") protected String xyz;
    
    // CDI injected fields
    @Inject protected SomeUtility util;
}
```

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService extends BaseService
{
    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

```
// QuuxService.java
@Path("/{id}/quux")
public class QuxxService extends BaseService
{   
    @GET @Path("abc")
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("def")
    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

Inside of the `get*` methods, the CDI injection (miraculously) works correctly: the `util` field is not null. Unfortunately, the JAX-RS injection does *not* work; `id` and `xyz` are `null` in the `get*` methods of `FooService` and `QuuxService`.

#### Is there a fix or workaround for this problem?

Given that the CDI works as I'd like it to, I'm wondering if the failure to inject `@PathParam`s (etc.) into subclasses is a bug or just part of the JAX-RS spec.

---

Another approach I have already tried is using `BaseService` as a single point of entry that delegates to `FooService` and `QuuxService` as needed. This is basically as described in [RESTful Java with JAX-RS](http://books.google.com/books?id=_jQtCL5_vAcC&lpg=PP1&dq=restful%20java%20with%20jax-rs&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) using subresource locators.

```
// BaseService.java
@Path("{id}")
public class BaseService
{
    @PathParam("id") protected String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") protected String xyz;
    @Inject protected SomeUtility util;
    
    public BaseService () {} // default ctor for JAX-RS
    
    // ctor for manual "injection"
    public BaseService(String id, String xyz, SomeUtility util)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.xyz = xyz;
        this.util = util;
    }
    
    @Path("foo")
    public FooService foo()
    {
        return new FooService(id, xyz, util); // manual DI is ugly
    }
    
    @Path("quux")
    public QuuxService quux()
    {
        return new QuuxService(id, xyz, util); // yep, still ugly
    }
}
```

```
// FooService.java
public class FooService extends BaseService
{
    public FooService(String id, String xyz, SomeUtility util)
    {
        super(id, xyz, util); // the manual DI ugliness continues
    }
    
    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

```
// QuuxService.java
public class QuuzService extends BaseService
{
    public FooService(String id, String xyz, SomeUtility util)
    {
        super(id, xyz, util); // the manual DI ugliness continues
    }
    
    @GET @Path("abc")
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }
    
    @GET @Path("def")
    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

The downside to this approach is that neither CDI injection nor JAX-RS injection works in the subresource classes. The reason for this is fairly obvious<sup>2</sup>, but what that *means* is that I have to manually re-inject the fields into the subclasses' constructor, which is messy, ugly, and doesn't easily let me customize further injection. Example: say I wanted to `@Inject` an instance into `FooService` but not `QuuxService`. Because I'm explicitly instantiating the subclasses of `BaseService`, CDI injection won't work, so the ugliness is continued.

---

### tl;dr What's the right way to avoid repeatedly injecting fields across JAX-RS resource handler classes?

#### And why aren't inherited fields injected by JAX-RS, while CDI has no issues with this?

---

## Edit 1

With a bit of direction from [@Tarlog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547779/tarlog), I think I've found the answer to one of my questions,

> Why aren't inherited fields injected by JAX-RS?

In [JSR-311 §3.6](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-330003.6):

> If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then *all* of the annotations on the super class or interface method are ignored.

I'm sure that there's a real reason for this decision, but unfortunately that fact is working against me in this particular use case. I'm still interested in any possible workarounds.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The caveat with using field-level injection is that I'm now tied to per-request resource class instantiation, but I can live with that.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Because I'm the one calling `new FooService()` rather than the container/the JAX-RS implementation.</sub>

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure your caveat #1 is necessary though - at least with RESTeasy we have been able to use per-request field-level injection into singletons via RESTeasy's thread-local proxying.  Possibly Jersey does the same?

Comment: Either way, #1 really doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: The "real reason for [the  JSR-311 §3.6] decision," seems like a cop out to avoid having to bother define override behaviors: resources definitely _ought_ be able to be constructed by way of Java inheritance patterns.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a workaround I'm using:

Define a constructor for the BaseService with 'id' and 'xyz' as params:

```
// BaseService.java
public abstract class BaseService
{
    // JAX-RS injected fields
    protected final String id;
    protected final String xyz;

    public BaseService (String id, String xyz) {
        this.id = id;
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }
}
```

Repeat the constructor on all subclasses with the injects:

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService extends BaseService
{
    public FooService (@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("xyz") String xyz) {
        super(id, xyz);
    }

    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [Jax's JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/JSR311/) it seems someone asked for annotation inheritance as milestone for JAX-RS.

The feature you're looking for just doesn't exist in JAX-RS yet, however, would this work?
It's ugly, but prevents recurrent injection.

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    // JAX-RS injected fields
    @PathParam("id") protected String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") protected String xyz;

    // CDI injected fields
    @Inject protected SomeUtility util;

    @GET @Path("bar")
    public abstract Response getBar();

    @GET @Path("baz")
    public abstract Response getBaz();

    @GET @Path("abc")
    public abstract Response getAbc();

    @GET @Path("def")
    public abstract Response getDef();
}
```

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService extends BaseService
{
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

```
// QuuxService.java
@Path("/{id}/quux")
public class QuxxService extends BaseService
{   
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }

    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

Or in another workaround :

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    @PathParam("id") protected String id;
    @QueryParam("xyz") protected String xyz;

    // CDI injected fields
    @Inject protected SomeUtility util;

    @GET @Path("{stg}")
    public abstract Response getStg(@Pathparam("{stg}") String stg);

}
```

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService extends BaseService
{
    public Response getStg(String stg) {
        if(stg.equals("bar")) {
              return getBar();
        } else {
            return getBaz();
        }
    }
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}
```

But seeing how touchy you are, frankly, I doubt your frustration will go away with this ugly code :)

Comment: I don't think the first suggestion will work because of [JSR-311 §3.6](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-330003.6) - basically, putting ***any*** annotations on a subclass will cause ***all*** annotations on the superclass to be ignored.

Comment: This restriction is only for methods and parameters, not classes ?

Comment: I don't think so, and my 2nd attempt (in the question) backs that up. Also, direct quote from JSR-311 §3.6: _"If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the super class or interface method are ignored."_

Comment: Or what if you nest the classes ? If it still works according to the doc's quote, you could try getting the latest version from the repository see if they have started to add inheritance to @Path and @Provided (which unfortunately, I doubt).

Comment: There are multiple ways to take that quote, and as I see it, there are two scopes, the methods and the fields+class, your code doesn't work because you have an @Path on the subclasses which cancels the annotations on the fields. But that doesn't mean that having an annotation on a method, actually cancels the annotations on the main class.

Comment: @MattBall Just running into this today, and I agree with Gepsens on the reading of the spec.  I think it's meant as *"If a [method from a subclass or implementation] has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the [method from the super class or interface] are ignored."*  I think the idea is that all the annotations that get used for a method should be specified in one place, rather than half in one place and half in another.

Answer (score 3):

In RESTEasy one can construct a class, annotate with @*Param as usual, and finish by annotating the class @Form. This @Form class may then be a parameter injection into any other service's method call.
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/_Form.html

Answer (score 3):

I always had a feeling, that annotation inheritance makes my code unreadable, as it is not obvious from where/how it is injected (e.g on which level of the inheritance tree would it be injected and where was it overriden (or was it overriden at all)). Moreover, you have to make the variable protected (and probably NOT final), which makes the superclass leak its internal state and also may introduce some bugs ( at least I would always ask myself when calling an extended method: is the protected variable changed there?). IMHO it has nothing with DRY, as this is not encapsulation of logic, but encapsulation of injection, which seems exaggerated to me.

At the end I will cite from the JAX-RS spec, **3.6 Annotation Inheritance**

> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended
>   to always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation
>   inheritance.

PS: I admit that I use only sometimes annotation inheritance, but on the method level :)

Comment: Four years after I asked this question, I don't disagree with your opinion. But it is not an answer to the question here.

Comment: Well, your question is on the first page on google for "jaxrs inheritance", and it is probably never too late to improve the things. Agree that it is not an answer to your question, but I hoped only to show to the people a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

What is the motivation of avoiding parameters injections?
If the motivation is avoiding of repeating hard-coded strings, so you can easily rename them, you can reuse "constants":

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/" +  FooService.ID +"/foo")
public class FooService
{
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String XYZ= "xyz";
    public static final String BAR= "bar";

    @PathParam(ID) String id;
    @QueryParam(XYZ) String xyz;

    @GET @Path(BAR)
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path(BAR)
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}

// QuuxService.java
@Path("/" +  FooService.ID +"/quux")
public class QuxxService
{
    @PathParam(FooService.ID) String id;
    @QueryParam(FooService.XYZ) String xyz;

    @GET @Path("abc")
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path("def")
    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

(Sorry for posting the second answer, but it was too long to put it in a comment of the previous answer)

Comment: Spot on. That section doesn't mention inherited fields at all. But section 3.6 says _"If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the super class or interface method are ignored."_ This is probably the problem with the second approach I tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom provider, particularly via AbstractHttpContextInjectable:

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService
{
    @Context CommonStuff common;

    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}


@Provider
public class CommonStuffProvider
    extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<CommonStuff>
    implements InjectableProvider<Context, Type>
{

    ...

    @Override
    public CommonStuff getValue(HttpContext context)
    {
        CommonStuff c = new CommonStuff();
        c.id = ...initialize from context;
        c.xyz = ...initialize from context;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Granted, you'll have to extract the path parameters and/or the query parameters the hard way from HttpContext, but you'll do it once in one place.

Comment: This is a Jersey specific implementation, c/d?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam` or any other param, you can use `@Context UriInfo` to access any types of parameters. So your code could be:

```
// FooService.java
@Path("/{id}/foo")
public class FooService
{
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    public static String getIdParameter(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        return uriInfo.getPathParameters().getFirst("id");
    }

    @GET @Path("bar")
    public Response getBar() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path("baz")
    public Response getBaz() { /* snip */ }
}

// QuuxService.java
@Path("/{id}/quux")
public class QuxxService
{
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    @GET @Path("abc")
    public Response getAbc() { /* snip */ }

    @GET @Path("def")
    public Response getDef() { /* snip */ }
}
```

Pay attention that `getIdParameter` is static, so you can put it in some utility class and reuse accorss multiple classes.
UriInfo is guaranteed to be threadsafe, so you can keep resource class as singleton.

Comment: Using `UriInfo` is certainly fewer _injections_, but with M methods per class, N classes, and K parameters (the **same parameters** for every single method, regardless of which class the method is in) that's still N*K*M parameters that would have to be manually extracted by the programmer (me).

Comment: Either way, both of those approaches are more code than just copy-and-pasting the field-level injections into each class. Instead of N*K*M repeated code, that's N*K repeated code, since each method can use the fields rather than having to (explicitly) do any additional work per-method. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can try @BeanParam for all the repeating params. so rather than injecting them every time you can simply inject you customBean which will do the trick.

Another approach which is more cleaner is that you can inject

```
@Context UriInfo
```

or

```
@Context ExtendedUriInfo
```

to your Resource Class and in very method you can simply access them.
UriInfo is more flexible because your jvm will have one less java source file to manage and above all single instance of UriInfo or ExtendedUriInfo gives you a handle of a lot of things.

```
@Path("test")
public class DummyClass{

@Context UriInfo info;

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response getSomeResponse(){
     //custom code
     //use info to fetch any query, header, matrix, path params
     //return response object
}
```

Comment: UriInfo here can again be used to get any param:

String queryParam = info.getQueryParameters().getFirst("paramName");

Link for docs
[UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)