# Can JAX-RS construct an object using only @*Param annotations?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Is it possible to get a JAX-RS implementation such as RESTEasy to automatically construct an object containing only `@*Param` annotations, such as `@MatrixParam`? I have the following class representing pagination:

```
public class Pagination {
    @MatrixParam("after")  public String afterKey;
    @MatrixParam("from")   public String fromKey;
    @MatrixParam("to")     public String toKey;
    @MatrixParam("before") public String beforeKey;
    @MatrixParam("count")  public int count;
}
```

I'd like to pass it to JAX-RS methods such as this:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
Response asHtml(Pagination pagination);
```

I was hoping RESTEasy would call the default constructor and then inject the field values, but I get a "Could not find message body reader" error. Obviously, there is no message body, and adding a dummy `String` constructor did not help. Do I need to create my own `@Provider` for this? If so, could such a thing be made generic and leverage the built-in `@*Param` injection features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this a bit old subject, but JAX-RS 2.0 has @BeanParam annotation that does this.

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
Response asHtml(@BeanParam Pagination pagination);
```

Comment: This still appears to be omitted from the RESTEasy documentation, but presumably it is supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187414/123336) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875772/staying-dry-with-jax-rs), there's a RESTEasy-specific annotation, [`@Form`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Form), that allows this:

> This is a RESTEasy specific annotation that allows you to re-use any `@*Param` annotation within an injected class. RESTEasy will instantiate the class and inject values into any annotated `@*Param` or `@Context` property. This is useful if you have a lot of parameters on your method and you want to condense them into a value object.

The `@Form` annotation goes on the resource method parameter or resource field, not the value object class:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
Response asHtml(@Form Pagination pagination);
```

Other implementations may require an entity provider. From the JAX-RS spec ([JSR-339](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html)):

> **3.3.2.1 Entity Parameters**
>   The value of a parameter not annotated with `@FormParam` or any of the annotations listed in Section 3.2, called the entity parameter, is mapped from the request entity body. Conversion between an entity body and a Java type is the responsibility of an entity provider, see Section 4.2. Resource methods MUST have at most one entity parameter.