# Java Annotations - Inherit annotations and RESTful

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, jersey, jax-rs

### Basic Issue

I want to inherit annotations so I can declare abstract classes including annotations for configuration. Then you only have to extend this abstract class and implement all abstract methods without configuring anything.

```
public class A {

}

@MyAnno
public class B extends A {
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class C extends B {
    public void foo() {
        Magic.bar();
    }
}

@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnno {

}
```

But if I check with reflections, class C are not annotated with MyAnno. If I add `@MyAnno` to class C, it works. This seems strange for me.

### Jersey

In addition to my own annotations, I want to use Java RESTful Annotations like `@GET`, `@Path(""where/I/am)` and so on. [This should work!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916796/inheritance-with-jax-rs) But it doesn't and the subclass of the annotated superclass does not have ANY RESTful annotations or own annotations, nothing.

Comment: How are you checking for the annotation on class C?  (I assume you didn't really intend to write `class C extends C`.)

Comment: new Reflections(MyServer.class.getPackage().getName()).getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnno.class)  -   This works if I annotate the subclass itself. (Gradle: compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10')

Comment: I don't know what kind of reflection that library does, but simply doing `MyAnno anno = C.class.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class)` return the annotation. You can see the difference if you remove the `@Inherited`, the previous code will result in null

Comment: The code in your comment works fine for me, returns both `C` and `B`. Check your package.

Comment: Yeah... reading javadocs sometimes makes life easier. xD Any suggestions for libraries, to query all annotated class in a specific package?

Answer (score 0):

### Reflections

I was using `org.reflections` which does not output subclasses of annotated superclasses if these superclasses are not in the package path of the type search.

### Jersey

I had used 2.9.x while it was not running. Works fine in 2.21!
*Update: Remove `@PathParam` from implemented methods!*